# How to validate template driven form without model driven approach.?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation

I am trying to validate template driven form in Angular without two way databinding. I have done validation using `[(ngModel)]` but when i try to validate form without **MODEL** i get following error

**Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined**

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
        <h3>Angular 6 Template-Driven Form Validation</h3>
        <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text"
                   class="form-control"
                   name="username"
                   #userName
                   required
                   minlength="8"/>
            <div *ngIf="f.form.controls.username.invalid && f.form.controls.username.touched" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f.form.controls.username.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger">Username is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="f.form.controls.username.minlength" class="alert alert-danger">length should b 8 character</div>
            </div>
          </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" >Register</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It also not sending data to component when i click button.

this is component `TS file` .

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-template-driven-form',
  templateUrl: './template-driven-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./template-driven-form.component.css']
})
export class TemplateDrivenFormComponent  {

  // model: any = {};

  onSubmit(f) {
    // alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + f);
    console.log(f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Replace *f.form.controls.username.invalid* with *f.controls.username.invalid*

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i tried this but still same error occuring.

Comment: Show the ts code!

Comment: Where you declared `Form`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale check now  i added component TS file code in my Question .

Comment: @PrashantPimpale i am using Template driven forms. are you asking about 
 `formsModule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace:

```
f.form.controls.username.invalid
```

with

```
username.invalid
```

but its mandatory to use `ngModel`

so your HTML control:

```
<input type="text" ngModel class="form-control" name="username" #username="ngModel" required minlength="8"/>
```

Comment: Use only `username.invalid` remove `f.form.controls.`

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because it shouldn't.

[As you can see](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z6u9q8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), inputs that aren't bound with `ngModel` aren't part of your form.

So simply use `ngModel` and you should be good to go.